# Invariant Violation: Slider has been removed from react-native core

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, npm-start

1. i've been trying to upgrade react native expo-cli app and i got some issues ind fixed but this one i couldn't handle

i tried more than a version of

````
@react-native-community/slider
 from https://github.com/callstack/react-native-slider .

    
```ive tried to change it from node_modules >react-native>index.js also but for nothing, here is the full error i get when  i try build with npm start:

 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Slider has been removed from react-native core. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/slider' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/callstack/react-native-slider
````